# I can see the expanded usercards with my current reputation which is below the "Established User" privilege

Tags: support, reputation, privileges, user-card

I've just realized that I could see the expanded usercards on ServerFault and posted [this question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6645/i-can-see-the-expanded-usercards-with-my-current-reputation) on its Meta. Then I've got curious and checked the situation on other SE sites. It's the same for all of the sites. Did you implement a new rule where gaining the "Established User" badge in one site is enough to give it to all the other connected accounts or is this a system wide bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The privilege is not that you can *see* the expanded usercards but that you *have* (or more precisely: can choose to have) an expanded usercard yourself, i.e., others see an expanded usercard for your profile.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't aware of it because I've hadn't read it thoroughly. I've always thought it to be the other way.